# Trying to make a Javascript Array Print out using Inputted value

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

my first question would be am I correctly getting the value from id "textOne" into my var a? Second, I am supposed to have my while loop run "while the variable that represents the index value that I want to print" is greater than or equal to the minimum array value. Is my While loop condition correct?

I just basically want this to print out the correct number of indexes within my array based on the user input ranging from 1-5.

Thanks in advance.

```
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="JobDuties()" />
to see my top
<input type="text" id="textOne" />
job duties here 
<p id="answer"></p>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function JobDuties()
{
var x = "";
var a = document.getElementById('textOne').value;
var b = a - 1;
myduties = new Array();
myduties[0] = "Saab";
myduties[1] = "Volvo";
myduties[2] = "BMW";
myduties[3] = "Toyota";
myduties[4] = "Ford";
}
while (a>=0)
{
x = x + myduties[b];
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: you never readjust the a variable...so the while loop will run forever as it remains constant during the loop

Comment: To answer your first question: use `alert(a)` or `console.log(a)`, and find out for yourself if you're doing it right.  (Visually, it looks fine to me, but nothing is as definitive as running and debugging.)

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you want to print out the correct array value, not arrays, as there are not multiple.  PS>  People do not like homework questions on here if you do not say so because answering completely does not help you learn.  I will partially answer.

1. You do not need to loop through the array to look up a value.
2. You can initialize the array more easily.
   ["Saab", "Volvo", ... ]
3. You can reference a position in the array, like so for Saab as it is zero indexed
   myduties[0]
4. If you are going to loop, which I am still not seeing why you would do that.

Code below:

```
var i = 1; //The variable you increment up to the use input variable a
while(i =< myduties.length){
   if(i == a){ //if i and a are same then that position 
              //in the array will have the car type the user requested
      myduties[i-1] //and set it to the DOM or document element similar to what you already had
   }
   i = i + 1; //Increment i towards the one less than the length of the array   
}
```

Not perfect or checked but that should provide you with some pointers.

Comment: thanks for the help Ted. I am trying to figure this out on my own but I am having difficulty which is why I am looking for pointers here.